# apache2 and bugzilla help

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2, bugzilla

I have a problem with the bugzilla and restarting apache2. When i try to reload apache2 it says:

The apache2 configtest failed. Not doing anything. Output of config test was:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/bugzilla.conf: DocumentRoot must be a directory Action 'configtest' failed. The Apache error log may have more information.
```

The file configuration for bugzilla is:

```
ServerName www.bugzilla.sphinx.al 
ServerAdmin elio.pashaj@sphinx.al 
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/bugzilla

AddHandler cgi-script .cgi Options +ExecCGI DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.html
```

Can u help me with Syntax error on line 3 of `/etc/apache2/sites enabled/bugzilla.conf`: DocumentRoot must be a directory

Comment: Did you create "bugzilla" in "/var/www/html/"?

Comment: Yes i created it. It was running normally but after i tried to install asteriks and freePBX it showed me this problem. How to make DocumentRoot and directory?